# How to generate an inverse equivalent string key? (to get the descending sort)

Tags: .net, string, algorithm, sorting

Supose you have an int Key, that when shown and sorted together with other keys will be, of course, sorted following the natural numbers order.

So, to obtain the "Inverse" you can program...

```
int InverseSortKey = Int32.MaxValue - ArbitraryIntKey;
```

Question is: How to get a similar "inverse" value, but for strings?

Example:

```
string InverseSortKey = "ZZZZZZZZZ" - ArbirtraryStringKey; // Of course this don't compile.
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I'm finding this question hard to follow - could you give some examples please? I *think* I'm starting to get it, but I'm not sure... Also, it's going to be important to know *exactly* how the method compares strings - e.g. is it culture-sensitive? Is there a maximum size of your input key?

Comment: For signed ints like `Int32`, the inverse would be `-DataKey`; for unsigned ints it would be `UInt32.MaxValue - DataKey`.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your attention. Question was changed to expose the core idea without unnecesary context (think of it as an indirect way to get an "orderby descending").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naive solution (**updated - works if you know the maximum length of all the strings**)

```
String data;
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(maxLength);
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    Char  c = i < data.length ? data[i] : 0;
    resultBuilder.Append(Char.MaxValue - c);
}
String result = resultBuilder.ToString();
```

**Does not take into account** the fact that string sorting may vary by culture and does not necessarily match the numerical values of Chars. A full solution would take an ordered list of all the <s>Chars</s> valid character sequences (in the particular expected encoding of these strings) by sort order, and then for each char pick the one that's the reverse.

**Further disclaimer**: Don't use this solution unless you can assume that the strings are single-byte encoded and sorted exactly by numerical order.

Comment: Also doesn't work with "A" and "AA" - it will effectively transform them to "Z" and "ZZ" (for some suitable Z) which will order them in the wrong way. That's why I asked whether there was a maximum input size :)

Comment: This will fail if there are Unicode surrogate code points in the string, or if `Char.MaxValue - c` maps to a surrogate code point. In addition, there are 66 values that are defined as "not a character". Generating any of those characters in a string is going to cause some interesting problems when it comes time to compare it. Using `StringComparison.Ordinal` would probably work, but any other type of comparison will likely behave badly.

Comment: Jim - right. As I started the answer: a naive solution. I'll add more warnings...